# If an Azure Deployment slot it is turned off are you still charged for the machine it runs on?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a few Azure websites running on Reserved instances that have Auto-scale turned on so they will take 1->6 servers but are usually just running on one server.   I am trying to set up hot-swapping so that when I deploy there is no down time.    I have created a deployment slot but am I charged extra for the deployment slot?   Even if it is turned off?

Answer (score 5):

This is the only reference I could find relating to this: [Managing Multiple Windows Azure Web Site Environments...](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/managing-multiple-windows-azure-web-site-environments-using-visual-studio-publishing-profiles)

To quote:

> That’s the only site that would cost money, so the development and
>   staging sites would have no impact on the cost I’ll incur for this
>   setup.

I believe that the slots are part of the instance, and that the number of slots that are in use makes no difference in pricing - they are tied to the instance.

Anecdotally, I run a number of slots for QA, Staging and other environments, and the cost has not changed with respect to the number of slots used.

Comment: You're correct, slots do not have their own resources.  They run on the same machine(s) as the live instance.  This is why you would want to do any load testing on a completely separate instance and not on a deployment slot of your production instance.